# After sending data to the server by threading.Timer(700ms), I received in other side 685ms?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I have been developing an application for measuring the gap between two frames to measure the time on the stopwatch by the camera, so I need to trigger a function after a specific time to send data to the server (Server-TCP). but I have one issue sometimes the server receive request less than the specified time, for example, if I run a thread with Timer 700ms, I find some requests inside the server such as 0.682,0.690,0.692,0.699 even if I calculate the gap in the real-image it also the same.

the normal behavior I expected to be if the function Trigger after 700ms, and I do some process, It must be bigger than 700 ms, this is the normal behavior.

I don't know where the mistake I made, and how that was possible to happen, all requests have a unique name, so it's easy to trace them.

this the main core in which I trigger the method to send requests to a server.

```
#2nd image

    def generate2ndTicketBasedonTime(trackedObject, attributes, object_id,event_obj):

    try:
        while not event_obj.wait(0.700):
            ImageProcessing.getInstance().serviceSnapshot(camera, DataToQeue)
            event_obj.set()
            pass
```

```
#1st image

    def snapshot
    ImageProcessing.getInstance().serviceSnapshot(camera, DataToQeue)
    event_obj = threading.Event()
    threading.Thread(target=generate2ndTicketBasedonTime, args=[self, self.attributes, self.car.object_id,event_obj]).start()
```

```
# client-side -< send data to the server

        def sendRequestToCameraService(self, data):
        Request = {'cameraRequest': json.dumps(data)}
        self.SendToServer(Request)



    def SendToServer(self, data):
        try:
            if(self.isConnected):
                data = json.dumps(data).encode()
                dataSize = struct.pack("<i", len(data))
                self.currentSocket.sendall(b'\xAA\xBB'+dataSize+data+b'\xCC\xDD')
                self.triggerTime = time.time()
        except BrokenPipeError:
            self.isConnected = False
```

```
    #server setting


    def run(self):
        srv_address = "0.0.0.0"
        srv_port = 4504
        srv_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        srv_sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        srv_sock.bind((srv_address, int(srv_port)))
        srv_sock.listen(5)
        while True:
            cl_sock, cl_address = srv_sock.accept()
            ClientHandler(cl_sock, cl_address, f"Client -{len(self.clients)}")
```

example for the case which I'm facing

[image for gap time between client and server-side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAVwm.png)

[image gap time before trigger the 2nd method in the clock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0y8DZ.png)

[image for 300ms gap time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeCbF.png)

Comment: `event_obj.wait(0.700)` what is `event_obj`? What time/delay are you actually measuring, and how?

Comment: I was trying different methods because I thought maybe the issue from it but it is similar to `time.sleep(0.700)`

Comment: if you pay attention to the images in the attachments at the end of the question. 

you will see the real difference after the function finished it was 704ms, before submitting the server it was 702ms, in the server-side 0.682ms

Answer (score 0):

I figure out the issue, it was the camera that return the frame before the specific time for a mysterious reason.

1- I tried the code without socket and threads, to avoid complexity so the main problem was from the camera

2- there is a slight difference between the applications when they start up(take time.time()) so now I'm sending the timestamp from the main application to other servers in the request, so the sequences for the process seem good now.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).